# Windows sript to automate SSHFS connection at user login login

Tags: windows, sshfs

I would like to use task scheduler to run script on user login which connects to online storage which is then mapped as a network drive. Currently works but I have to click connect manually each time which stops any apps indexing files on server from seeing those files until connected.

Is this possible with a script?

Thanks,

I have tried using task scheduler but it requires a script to be ran. I have no idea how to write this script.